# Strange cropping issue while converting svg to png using Imagick in PHP

Tags: php, svg, png, imagick, inkscape

I am trying to convert a bunch of svg images into png. Below is the snippet of the Imagick part:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel($options->iconsBgColor)); //$options->iconsBgColor is like #00ff00
$im->readImageBlob( $svg );
$im->setImageResolution(288,288);
$im->resizeImage(512, 512, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$im->setImageFormat( "png32" );
$im->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_UNDEFINED);
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(0);
$im->writeImage( $imageSrcPngDir );
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

This mostly works as expected. But in the images where there is a big white space on top and bottom of the images, it gets cropped on the bottom in the png file. Like in the example below:
[image: Image where it is getting cropped]

Here is the svg for the above png:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg filter="url(#shadow)" style="width:512px; height:512px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-215 -215 942 942">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#0000ff;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:18px;}</style>
        <filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="11.636363636364"/>
            <feOffset dx="17.454545454546" dy="17.454545454546" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feFlood flood-color="#04040C" flood-opacity="1"/>
            <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <title>imdb-icon</title>
    <g id="imdb-icon">
        <g id="imdb-icon-2" data-name="imdb-icon">
            <path class="cls-1" d="M506,327.03028v-92.721c-4.04258-27.411-33.82293-27.27624-33.82293-27.27624-15.82225-.146-26.0971,6.27726-32.20589,12.24007V157.67979H386.74382v193.606h48.7356a24.443,24.443,0,0,1,1.97638-11.88071c5.6147,6.513,16.4735,15.08106,34.72127,14.91266C472.17707,354.31776,506,354.32222,506,327.03028Zm-48.91524-15.96816a12.39325,12.39325,0,0,1-12.39722,12.39722H437.9499V236.13963h6.73764a12.39321,12.39321,0,0,1,12.39722,12.39723Z"/>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M339.32932,157.6843H250.7142V351.31552h88.61512a31.23974,31.23974,0,0,0,31.2418-31.2418V188.92611A31.23971,31.23971,0,0,0,339.32932,157.6843ZM320.94825,303.87277a15.40325,15.40325,0,0,1-15.40086,15.41087h-3.80027V191.73627h3.80027a15.40328,15.40328,0,0,1,15.40086,15.41086Z"/>
            <polygon class="cls-1" points="233.833 157.68 233.833 351.286 189.062 351.286 189.062 228.346 170.151 351.286 139.978 351.286 120.944 227.538 120.944 351.286 74.185 351.286 74.185 157.68 141.191 157.68 154.666 245.28 168.141 157.68 233.833 157.68"/>
            <rect class="cls-1" x="6" y="157.67984" width="53.15995" height="193.63967"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Now when I reduce the padding on the top and bottom by increasing the size of the drawing by manipulating the viewBox attribute, the image renders as expected, like shown below.

[image]

Below is the svg for the above png (this is working as expected):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg filter="url(#shadow)" style="width:512px; height:512px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-31 -31 573 573">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#0000ff;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:18px;}</style>
        <filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="11.636363636364"/>
            <feOffset dx="17.454545454546" dy="17.454545454546" result="offsetblur"/>
            <feFlood flood-color="#04040C" flood-opacity="1"/>
            <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <title>imdb-icon</title>
    <g id="imdb-icon">
        <g id="imdb-icon-2" data-name="imdb-icon">
            <path class="cls-1" d="M506,327.03028v-92.721c-4.04258-27.411-33.82293-27.27624-33.82293-27.27624-15.82225-.146-26.0971,6.27726-32.20589,12.24007V157.67979H386.74382v193.606h48.7356a24.443,24.443,0,0,1,1.97638-11.88071c5.6147,6.513,16.4735,15.08106,34.72127,14.91266C472.17707,354.31776,506,354.32222,506,327.03028Zm-48.91524-15.96816a12.39325,12.39325,0,0,1-12.39722,12.39722H437.9499V236.13963h6.73764a12.39321,12.39321,0,0,1,12.39722,12.39723Z"/>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M339.32932,157.6843H250.7142V351.31552h88.61512a31.23974,31.23974,0,0,0,31.2418-31.2418V188.92611A31.23971,31.23971,0,0,0,339.32932,157.6843ZM320.94825,303.87277a15.40325,15.40325,0,0,1-15.40086,15.41087h-3.80027V191.73627h3.80027a15.40328,15.40328,0,0,1,15.40086,15.41086Z"/>
            <polygon class="cls-1" points="233.833 157.68 233.833 351.286 189.062 351.286 189.062 228.346 170.151 351.286 139.978 351.286 120.944 227.538 120.944 351.286 74.185 351.286 74.185 157.68 141.191 157.68 154.666 245.28 168.141 157.68 233.833 157.68"/>
            <rect class="cls-1" x="6" y="157.67984" width="53.15995" height="193.63967"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I have compared the 2 svg files and viewBox is the only thing that is different.
[image]

**Any idea how can I resolve this?**

Comment: My first guess would be that, when you are "regex to manipulate the viewBox", you are making the viewBox smaller than the actual document contents.  But we can't really tell unless you provide the modified SVG code for the top image.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thanks. Give me a while, I will update the question with the modified svg.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have updated the question with the svg that is actually rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the height of the `filter` area from 200% to 300% resolved the issue.

```
<filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="300%">
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my suspicions about the altered viewBox were unfounded. That looks okay.

But what is up with the filter effect you are adding?  You didn't mention that.  It's basically an unconfigured/misconfigured drop shadow filter. But it is missing a lot of attributes.  For example `stdDeviation` is not set in the `<feGaussianBlur>` filter element. It's possible that ImageMagick does not like that.  Does it still clip when you remove the filter from the SVG (i.e. remove `filter="url(#shadow)"`)?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. You were right, the `<feGaussianBlur>` is what was causing the issue, without it the rendering works fine. But actually, I am letting the user add an optional shadow too. In which case the issue still persists. I have updated the whole question with new information. Please have a look.

Comment: @Roy I think it is likely still related to ImageMagicks's handling of filters. Or whatever ImageMagick uses for the SVG rendering.  You might want to file a bug with them - if there isn't one already.